# How to use the jquery ui draggable method on an canvas object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, canvas, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to allow the user the ability to move a rectangle around a canvas element using the draggable method.

This was my original thought but it doesn't work.

I have a fiddle set up at http://jsfiddle.net/r2Zbe/

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var door = bgContext.strokeRect(20, 20, 50, 150);
    door.draggable();
});
```

Comment: draggable works on DOM elements, it does not work on objects in a canvas.

Comment: Adeneo means, you can do it, but to achieve something on canvas there'll be looooots of code, and not using jQ-UI for sure, but rather with custom drag events, animations, frameRates, ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about using jQuery UI with canvas, but if you are working with canvas you may want to take a look at EaselJS. It makes everything, including drag and drop, very simple.

[EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS)

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down, it is a very practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

jCanvas library says they can let you drag on canvas with jQuery. http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/

They say nothing about jQuery UI though.

Disclaimer: I've never tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like fabricJs, it is much cleaner and easy to use.